# Python Selenium - browser.find_element_by_class_name - returns error SOMETIMES?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm a newB to Python - going through "Automate the Boring Stuff" - Al Swigart.

I've written a script to play the "2048" tile game at "https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048".  After several moves, the tile game will "max out" and pop up a "Game Over!" which I haven't figured out how to read - so instead I've implemented logic to read the score after a series of every 4 moves, figure out if the score has stopped increasing, and if so, Game Over!

What I'm finding is my statement to read the score, is returning an error *sometimes*.  I can't figure out why it either just works, or doesn't.  Why does it return an error, sometimes?!?

I put it in a try/except block, so if I get an error, I count it up.  Sometimes it's a few, sometimes it's about half the time.

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks.

```
output...
Evolutions: 40   oldScore1308    newScore: 1736
Evolutions: 41   oldScore1736    newScore: 1736
GAME OVER!
Good Game.

Final Score:
Evolutions: 41   OldScore1736    NewScore: 1736   Errors:23
Pausing before program closes.  Hit enter to continue.
```

Code:

```
#! python


import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  # import Keys to send special keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time


def opensite():
    # open browser
    global browser  # stop chrome window from closing by itself.
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get("https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048")

    return browser


def botKeys():
    # function to send arrow keys to browser :up, right, down, left.
    w = 0.025  # time to wait between plays
    try:
        element = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

        gameOn = True
        counter = 0
        oldScore = 0
        error = 0

        while gameOn == True:

            counter += 1

            # Send keys to move pieces
            time.sleep(w)
            element.send_keys(Keys.UP)

            time.sleep(w)
            element.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)

            time.sleep(w)
            element.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)

            time.sleep(w)
            element.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)

            # check the score.  Keep track of it to determine if GAME OVER!
            try:
                newScore = browser.find_element_by_class_name(
                    "score-container"
                )  # get the object with the score.
                newScore = int(
                    newScore.text
                )  # read the text of the object, which is the score in a string.  Convert it to an integer.

                print(
                    f"Evolutions: {counter}   oldScore{oldScore}    newScore: {newScore}"
                )
                if oldScore != newScore:
                    oldScore = newScore
                else:  # old and new are the same, game over
                    print(f"GAME OVER!\nGood Game.")
                    print(f"\nFinal Score:")
                    print(
                        f"Evolutions: {counter}   OldScore{oldScore}    NewScore: {newScore}   Errors:{error}"
                    )
                    gameOn = False

            except ValueError:
                error += 1  # count value errors, but that's all.

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Could not find element")

    input("Pausing before program closes.  Hit enter to continue.")


def main():

    # TODO  open the site
    driver = opensite()
    # TODO  send keystrokes
    botKeys()
    driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: you should display HTML when you get error to see what you really get in HTML - maybe it really doesn't have this element.

Comment: or maybe you should sleep after move (even  few milliseconds) and browser will have time to create this element

Comment: BTW: you should send `driver` to `botKeys(driver)` and then you don't need `global browser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you display error

```
except ValueError as ex:
    error += 1
    print(ex)
```

then you see what is the problem

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3060\n+20'
```

Problem is that sometimes it displays result `3060` with points which it adds to result `+20`.

It works correctly when you split it on `\n` and get first elements

```
newScore = int(
    newScore.text.split('\n')[0]
)
```

---

To recognize `Game Over` you need

```
game_over = driver.find_element_by_class_name("game-over")  #
```

but it raises error when there is no class `game-over` so I would use `find_elements` (with `s` at the end of word `find_elements`) to get empty list instead of rasing error.

BTW: I changed some names because [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  # import Keys to send special keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time


def opensite():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048")
    return driver


def bot_keys(driver):
    '''Function to send arrow keys to browser :up, right, down, left.'''

    wait = 0.025  # time to wait between plays

    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

        game_on = True
        counter = 0
        old_score = 0
        new_score = 0
        error = 0

        while game_on:

            counter += 1

            # Send keys to move pieces
            time.sleep(wait)
            element.send_keys(Keys.UP)

            time.sleep(wait)
            element.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)

            time.sleep(wait)
            element.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)

            time.sleep(wait)
            element.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)

            # check the score.  Keep track of it to determine if GAME OVER!
            try:

                new_score = driver.find_element_by_class_name("score-container")  # get the object with the score.

                new_score = int(new_score.text.split('\n')[0])  # read the text of the object, which is the score in a string.  Convert it to an integer.

                print(f"Evolutions: {counter:5} | Old Score: {old_score:5} | New Score: {new_score:5}")

                old_score = new_score

                game_over = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("game-over")  # get the object with the score.
                #print('game_over:', len(game_over))

                if game_over:
                    print("\nGAME OVER!\n")
                    print("Final Score:")
                    print(f"Evolutions: {counter:5} | New Score: {new_score:5} | Errors: {error}")
                    game_on = False

            except ValueError as ex:
                print('ex:', ex)
                error += 1  # count value errors, but that's all.

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Could not find element")

    input("\nPausing before program closes.  Hit enter to continue.")


def main():
    driver = opensite()
    bot_keys(driver)
    driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Maybe next step would be to use [Gym](https://gym.openai.com/) (or something similar) to use `Reinforcement Learning` (`Machine Learning`, `Artificial Intelligence`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks good! Here's my solution:

```
'''
2048
2048 is a simple game where you combine tiles by sliding them up, down, 
left, or right with the arrow keys. You can actually get a fairly high score 
by repeatedly sliding in an up, right, down, and left pattern over and over 
again. Write a program that will open the game at https://gabrielecirulli 
.github.io/2048/ and keep sending up, right, down, and left keystrokes to 
automatically play the game.
'''

from selenium import webdriver
import random
import time
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException

os.makedirs('2048', exist_ok=True)
bestScoreCurrent, check, attempts = 0, False, 0
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/')


def saveScreenshot(screenshot, filename, best, timeLoc):
    filename = f'2048\{best}_{filename}_{timeLoc}.png'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as elemFile:
        elemFile.write(screenshot)


def tryRetryButton():
    gameScreenshot = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        '.game-container').screenshot_as_png
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.retry-button').click()
        return True, gameScreenshot
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        return False, gameScreenshot


def botLogic():
    for key in [Keys.UP, Keys.RIGHT, Keys.DOWN, Keys.LEFT]:
        bestScorePossible = int(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            ".best-container").text)
        time.sleep((random.randint(5, 10) / 20))
        userElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
        userElem.send_keys(key)
    return bestScorePossible


while True:

    bestScorePossible = botLogic()
    bestScoreScreenshot = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        '.best-container').screenshot_as_png
    check, gameScreenshot = tryRetryButton()

    if check and bestScorePossible > bestScoreCurrent:
        attempts += 1
        print(
            f'New best score {bestScorePossible}! Total attempts {attempts}')
        bestScoreCurrent = bestScorePossible
        timeLoc = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())
        saveScreenshot(bestScoreScreenshot, 'bestScore', bestScoreCurrent, timeLoc)
        saveScreenshot(gameScreenshot, 'bestGameWindow', bestScoreCurrent, timeLoc)
```